# For android(requests) and API security, are both HTTPS and oauth2 necessary?

Tags: android, node.js, express, https, oauth-2.0

Beginner here, I'm currently using an express http server but I'm wondering what the best practices are to ensure the safety of my requests and user info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want to use OAuth for.

At minimum, https is a must. Also have a look at [jwt](http://jwt.io/) for securing JSON requests (will need to implement support on the server-side) if you have control over the server implementation.

Comment: It's a chat application using socket.io but I want to make sure my post requests are secure as well. So I assume https and oauth2 using jwt is the best way about it?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion that you should implement OAuth2 to your app, cause it's a chat app and you should protect your clients data and also you should use SSL(HTTPS) certificate.
and here is [library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager) for IOS and [Library](https://github.com/AliAbozaid/OAuth2Library) for android you can use it to implement it in your mobile app.